# 0x80041008 error when trying to change Log On account on SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a "Mirroring" homework in SQL Server, but i get 14148 Error when trying to start mirroring. According to some videos this problem can be solved changing SQL Server services account to the same account for both instances. But when i try i receive this error
[Invalid Parameter 0x80041008]

[image: 1]

What should i do?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Are you setting the password in Services.msc or using SQL Server Configuration Manager? Have you tried [troubleshooting the mirroring error](https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/database-mirroring-error-1418/#) first?

Comment: maybe this can help:
https://mostafaelmasry.com/2013/01/04/mssql-2008r2-mirroring-in-workgroup/